# SciFi/Horror movie featuring alien city landing in a US desert, forshadowed by cave paintings

Tags: movie, aliens, story-identification

I finally registered in hope of finding people who maybe know the movie I have been looking for for ages...

The movie takes place in a very dry country in the States. I would guess it is Texas or so. The protagonist lives in or visits a small desert town and hears about some rumors of a coming event (or something like that). Searching the vicinity of the town he finds some carvings/paintings in a cave depicting some kind of alien city/huge UFO that is going to land.

And well, in the end it really lands and the inhabitants are not very friendly. As far as I can remember they look like humans with armor or cyborgs with huge weapons or so.  The "visitors" came with one or more huge cities the city/cities had a dome or shield and were built upon some kind of structure with landing supports and their leader was marching down some kind of huge ramp, had a big weapon and I think a bald head with pipes leading from his neck/head to his "armor".

Before they did land, they send some scouts who checked the area, oh yeah and this was definitely in color that much I know for sure.

What non American studio could have made such a movie in the 70s or 80s? It definitely was produced in the west.

I watched it as a little kid (thanks dad for the nightmares) in the mid 80s. So it is kinda old.

Comment: While you may have seen it in the 70s or 80s, could it have been produced earlier?

Comment: I watched it somewhere between 85 to 89 I am almost positive but I doubt it was made earlier then 1970 just from what little I do remember of the way it looked.

Comment: "episodes"? Is this a movie or a TV-series?

Comment: Oops, did not mean to post that, but yes it could be a TV series, honestly I do not remember enough to say one way or the other, I have already checked 80's Twilight Zone's and could not find one that matched.

Comment: I definitely remember your description of the leader... racking my brains...

Comment: This strikes me as similar to the opening sequence of *The Fifth Element* (which takes place in an Egyptian temple in 1914), but it was released in 1997. Are you sure you aren't conflating two hazily-remembered movies?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[The Time Guardian (1987)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094152/)**

Just found out on a different forum that it is a movie called The Time Guardian (1987), I watched the trailer for it and it is the movie, I'm afraid the description might have been a little off, but it has been a really long time since I have seen it, thanks for everyone's help.