# Movie with evil killer robot, time travel, bent jail cell bars. (not terminator)

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have a movie that is stuck in my head but I don't know what it is called.  It isn't high production, I can't find it on websites for finding a moive and it isn't in any list anywhere.

I remember one scene specifically.  The hero man is at the jail in a sherriff's office and the robot attacks.  The hero locks himself in a jail cell to keep away from the robot but then it slowly walks up and uses its clamp like hands to bend the bars on the door.  I think the hero then destroys it somehow in a blaze of gunfire.

Comment: Any chance it is [Future War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_War) ? "The Runaway is interrogated by federal agents. They present to him a dinosaur collar found on the beach. The Cyborg Master breaks into the police station during the interrogation and The Runaway manages to escape in the confusion. "

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12589/scifi-horror-movie-featuring-alien-city-landing-in-a-us-desert-forshadowed-by-c

Answer (score 6):

[The Time Guardian.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094152/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)

> In the distant future, the human race nears extinction and a new race of beast-like creatures rule the earth. The few surviving people live in the City, a huge protected construction with the ability to travel in both space and time. The City travels back to our time to save humanity...

[image: Robot bending cell bars]

Comment: If that is the right answer, DON'T under any circumstances watch it. It is a bad, bad movie.